# Usar HTMLDOM en un proyecto De React

Tags: reactjs, simple-html-dom

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de react y quiero crear un componente con un texto al cuál se le subraye una parte de manera dinámica. Pero me da error el codigo de componente es el siguiente:

```
const test = document.getElementsByClassName("texto-testimonio");
  test.innerHTML = modifiedString;
  console.log(test.innerHTML);
  /*return test;*/
}

function Testimonio(props) {
  destacar(props.testimonio,props.destacado)
  return(
    <div className='contenedor-testimonio'>
        <img 
          className='imagen-testimonio'
          src={require(`../imagenes/${props.imagen}.png`)}
          alt='Foto de Emma'/>
        <div className='contenedor-texto-testimonio'>
          <p className='cargo-testimonio'><strong>{props.cargo}</strong> en <strong>{props.empresa}</strong></p>
          <p className='texto-testimonio'></p>
          
          
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Testimonio;
```

El error que me sale en consola es el siguiente

```
caught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estás usando `document.getElementsByClassName`, esto te regresa un arreglo de elementos que tengan el nombre que quieres. Al ser un arreglo, tienes que iterar sobre ellos o si no puedes agregarle la posición para usar el elemento que quieres.

[Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

Estas asertando **`TypeError`** porque es probable que no estas definiendo la variable `modifiedString`. Si quieres cambiar el texto podrías chequear un valor determinado usando `useEffect` y `useState` cuando el documento del navegador este ejecutandose y modifique el texto o retorne **null**.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Testimonio({ props }) {
  const [isComponentMounted, setIsComponentMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => setIsComponentMounted(true), [])

  destacar(props.testimonio, props.destacado)
  return(
    <div className='contenedor-testimonio'>
        <img 
          className='imagen-testimonio'
          src={require(`../imagenes/${props.imagen}.png`)}
          alt='Foto de Emma'/>
        <div className='contenedor-texto-testimonio'>
          <p className='cargo-testimonio'><strong>{props.cargo}</strong> en <strong>{props.empresa}</strong></p>
          <p className='texto-testimonio'>{() => {isComponentMounted ? props.modifiedString : null}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Testimonio;
```